# Testing the paper is finish in my printer

Tags: vb.net, printing

Someone knows how to get a warning in my  VB program when the paper in the printer was over.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodeProject article "[Monitoring a Printer Queue in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printwatchvbnet.aspx)" or the .NET 3.0 [`PrinterQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx) class may be what you are looking for.

If you go the `PrinterQueue` route, there is a [`PrintSystemJobInfo.IsCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo.iscompleted.aspx) property you can inspect.

Comment: I think he means a warning when the paper has run out

Comment: I mean a warning when the paper is over.